# Multiple databases vs single db

Tags: php, mysql

In a web application, is better have all the datas into a single db or create a database for each customer?

Single db will be easier and faster to mantain (updates, backups etc etc), but if anything goes bad.. everyone will be blocked.

Maybe i can create single tables and then grant permissions, but i'm not a guru..

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Indeed, but that maxim holds true for any scenario.

Comment: @Piskvor that answers the very question.

Comment: And what if your webserver goes down? Would your solution be to use a separate webserver for every client as well? Look into clustering, backup servers (master/slave), high availability, and such... Using separate databases would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: There is no correct answer to this question. It depends on too many things.

Comment: @Dan Grossman can you tell me? maybe i can add that in the question

Comment: @wimvds: Possibly, depending on the expected load in the app tier and various other factors; likely with something like HAProxy in front. As you note, that's an *extremely* wide topic to get into...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends - I've seen apps that used the same database for hundreds of clients (with 10000s of users in total) run quite smoothly. In my opinion, depending on the usage scenarios, either have all clients use the same db (and deal with scaling issues accordingly), or have clients use different *servers* (easier to deploy, harder to maintain - as you can end up with many versions of your software, each *slightly* different from the other).

Multiple databases on the same server is a weird half-breed which brings together the disadvantages of both approaches.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to account for "anything goes bad" is not multiple databases, it's multiple database servers. Use a single database, and investigate clustering.

Comment: ok, but what about customizations? i mean, i have to do something for a customer only, this will messy anything

Comment: If it's a custom app, then yes, it goes in a different database. But custom apps are the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use single databass instead of multiple databases or multiple tables. Your table should have unique id for each customer. "anything goes bad" threat could be rmoved by replication of db server.

Comment: All tables should have a primary key!

Answer (score 0):

The more robust approach here is to use a db for each customer.
This way it is easier to backup and update and much more ERROR PRONE!

Comment: I'd say this is *hard(er) to maintain* ("did I modify each customer's table structure?"), but how is it more error-prone?

Comment: in case you want to update a few customer tables - the one who does it makes a mistake and the whole db is gone (if you you one db for each customer there will be only one db be gone)